# List rules using iptables in a customized way

Tags: firewall, iptables

How to list the iptables rules in  a customized way?
Like:

target protocol portnumber src dest

the order could be changed but I dont want the name of protocols, just number (like 80 instead of http)

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

`iptables` does not support a generic `--output-format` option or similar, but if all you want is to have numbers instead of names, use the `-n` option. From `man iptables`:

```
-n, --numeric
   Numeric  output.   IP  addresses  and  port  numbers  will be
   printed in numeric format.  By default, the program will  try
   to  display  them  as  host names, network names, or services
   (whenever applicable).
```

If you want to do something fancy, you're on your own - I'd suggest you start by running `iptables-save` and pipe the result to `awk` or something like that.